# Small question about $f^{-1}(g^{-1}\mathcal{H})\cong (g\circ f)^{-1}\mathcal{H}$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is on page 56 in the second edition of Görtz/Wedhorn, where it is being said that for continuous maps $X\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow}Y\stackrel{g}{\rightarrow}Y$ and a presehaf $\mathcal{H}$ on $Z$, one can deduce the ismorphism $f^{-1}(g^{-1}\mathcal{H})\cong (g\circ f)^{-1}\mathcal{H}$ from the adjunction isomorphism of direct- and inverse image and $(g\circ f)_{*}=g_*\circ f_*$. I see this using the Yoneda lemma - or, rather, that's what I think - but at this point Yoneda's lemma has not been treated in the book. So my questions is what is the correct argument here for this sentence that I should keep in mind. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know what the authors had intended, but if you asked me to prove the desired isomorphism using adjunctions, I would almost surely invoke the Yoneda lemma as well.